# how can i draw on any window using python

Tags: python, drawing

I am making a tutorial to explain things to others. For that tutorial i am trying to make a python program (which is like the paint app)

Which we all use in windows. To draw with pen,brush and to draw shapes like square,circle and have a option for color piker to choose colour to draw.

I already tried with the `from tkinter import choosecolor` to create paint like software in python.

But with that it draws only on a tkinter canvas.

But i don't want to draw on a canvas i want to draw it on live screen while i make the tutorial.

example image is shown below

[image]

> I am trying to make a gui window like this to choose color and pen tool to draw on the screen (eg.desktop,web browser etc).

[image]

Can anyone give me some suggestion on how can i draw like this on my desktop screen or on any window.

Comment: So just make a screenshot and put it in a `tkinter.Canvas` is okay.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA no i want to draw live like this (https://youtu.be/UNarqPBpWsw?t=300) see this example

Comment: Put it in a `Canvas` is the first step.You also need to create a `Toplevel()` to show the tool(adding word,drawing,creating line and so on).

Answer (score 5):

Although in your video,it seems that " draw directly on screen ".Actually,I think it didn't.

There is a easy example to "draw on the screen",You can modify it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab,ImageTk
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2) # windows 10

class ToolWin(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self._offsetx = 0
        self._offsety = 0
        self.wm_attributes('-topmost',1)
        self.penSelect = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.geometry('200x200')
        self.penModeId = None
        self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',self.clickTool) 
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>',self.moveTool) # bind move event

        draw = tk.Checkbutton(self,text="Pen",command=self.penDraw,variable=self.penSelect)
        draw.pack()
        cancel = tk.Button(self,text="Quit",command=root.destroy)
        cancel.pack()

    def moveTool(self,event):
        self.geometry("200x200+{}+{}".format(self.winfo_pointerx()-self._offsetx,self.winfo_pointery()-self._offsety))

    def clickTool(self,event):
        self._offsetx = event.x
        self._offsety = event.y

    def penDraw(self):
        if self.penSelect.get():
            self.penModeId = root.bind("<B1-Motion>",Draw)
        else:
            root.unbind('<B1-Motion>',self.penModeId)

def Draw(event):# r = 3
    fullCanvas.create_oval(event.x-3,event.y-3,event.x+3,event.y+3,fill="black")

def showTool(): # the small tool window
    toolWin = ToolWin()
    toolWin.mainloop()

root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.overrideredirect(1)

fullCanvas = tk.Canvas(root)
background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ImageGrab.grab(all_screens=True)) # show the background,make it "draw on the screen".
fullCanvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=background)
fullCanvas.pack(expand="YES",fill="both")

root.after(100,showTool)

root.mainloop()
```

Also,you can move the toolbar by dragging it.
(PS: I think you nearly finished it.)

Comment: the pen is not perfect it creates dots can't draw proper line. and this don't have a color chooser to draw with different colors.

Comment: @amit9867 Yes,I see your code has done it.You can add those function(like color chooser) to the class `ToolWin`.I just give you an idea.You can modify it to do what you want.